# If i am comparing a string in a list to a string variable, is it checking all the characters in the word or the word itself on the list

Tags: python, if-statement, iteration, comparison

I am a newbie programmer using Python. The example below is a function called censor that takes two strings, text and word, as input. It should return the text with the word you chose replaced with asterisks.

So for example, if text="hello and shoutout to everyone", and word="everyone", the output should be:

"hello and shoutout to ********"

```
def censor(text, word):
    text = text.lower()
    text_to_list = text.split()
    for i in text_to_list:
        if i == word:
            text = text.replace(i, '*' * len(word))
    print(text)
```

My function above looks like it is doing the job, but when I set:
text="joey is a buggie bug", and word="bug", the buggie in the text string gets asterisk as well. Can someone tell me what am I missing or is the comparison type wrong. I tried to check the type for both 'i' and 'word' and they are both giving me "class string". Any help will be great.

Comment: you could use [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) here ``text.replace(word, "*" * len(word))`` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're replacing all instances of `word` if only one is found, you have to replace it each time manually:

```
def censor(text, word):
    text = text.lower()
    text_to_list = text.split()
    out = []
    for i in text_to_list:
        out.append('*' * len(word) if i == word else i)
    print(' '.join(out))
```

Comment: Thank you so much Francisco. Can you explain a little more why my code was part wrong? It looks like when i run the code eg. text="this hack is wack hack", word="hack", it displays it correctly for this instance (this **** is wack ****).

Comment: Because `"joey is a buggie bug".replace('bug', '***') == 'joey is a ***gie ***'`

Comment: ahhh i see it now. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: If that solved it, please mark the question as answered

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a comparison that before and after your "word" there are no symbols except for spaces